# Convergence of 1/n(n+1)

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Given the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n+1)}$$ I'm trying to prove that this series converges using the idea $$\frac{1}{n(n+1)} = \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1}$$ and then computing the partial sums of the series. I can see that the partial fractions will cancel $$\frac{1}{1} - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} . . .$$ hence the series converges to 1. This is not, however, sufficient proof of convergence.

Perhaps a relation to the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$$ would help?

Comment: The nice thing about telescoping series is that you can compute their partial sums. Try computing, explicitly, the partial sum $\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n(n+1)}$ for arbitrary $N$, using the telescoping to your advantage. You should see that you get a convergent sequence.

Comment: The definition of $\sum_1^{\infty}$ is $\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_1^k$, the limit of the partial sums. So, what do you get for $\sum_1^k$?

Comment: Yes. As this is a series with positive terms, using  *asymptotic equivalence* is the easiest way to prove it.

Comment: You were going in the right direction. Partial fractions is the way to go. Can you write it a little more formally? Remember that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{n(n+1)}\right)$ is short for $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{k(k+1)}\right)\right)$.

Comment: If you just want to show it converges, noting that the $n$-th term is between $0$ and $1/n^2$ is sufficient to show that the sum exists and lies between $0$ and $\pi^2/6$.  To show it converges to exactly $1$, taking the limit of the partial sums (which as noted can be evaluated exactly) is the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The really nice thing
about this sum is that
we can easily get the partial sums
and look at their limit.

Let
$s(m)
=\sum_{n=1}^m \frac{1}{n(n+1)}
$.

Then
(I'm doing this
in excruciating detail
to illustrate one way
of working with sums)

$\begin{array}\\
s(m)
&=\sum_{n=1}^m \frac{1}{n(n+1)}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^m (\frac{1}{n}-\frac1{n+1})\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^m \frac{1}{n}-\sum_{n=1}^m \frac1{n+1}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^m \frac{1}{n}-\sum_{n=2}^{m+1} \frac1{n}\\
&=1+\sum_{n=2}^m \frac{1}{n}-(\sum_{n=2}^{m} \frac1{n}+\frac1{m+1})\\
&=1-\frac1{m+1}\\
&\to 1
\qquad\text{as } m \to \infty\\
\end{array}
$

This will work for
$\sum_{n=1}^m \frac1{n(n+1)...(n+k-1)}
$
for any fixed $k$ -
this is the case $k=2$.
To see this,
note that

$\begin{array}\\
\frac1{n(n+1)...(n+k-1)}-\frac1{(n+1)...(n+k)}
&=\frac{n+k}{n(n+1)...(n+k-1)(n+k)}-\frac{n}{n(n+1)...(n+k)}\\
&=\frac{n+k-n}{n(n+1)...(n+k-1)(n+k)}\\
&=\frac{k}{n(n+1)...(n+k-1)(n+k)}\\
\end{array}
$

so

$\frac1{n(n+1)...(n+k-1)(n+k)}
=\frac1{k}(\frac1{n(n+1)...(n+k-1)}-\frac1{(n+1)...(n+k)})
$.

Comment: I hope that you do not mind. You made the interesting generalization and I could not resist ! Cheers and thanks for providing so interesting answers.

Comment: You are welcome. Note that telescoping works for $n(n+1)...(n+k)$ as well.

Answer (score 2):

We can actually calculate this series. Indeed, we have a telescope sum.
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+1)} &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right) \\
&= \lim_{t\to\infty} \left(\sum_{n=1}^{t} \left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right) \right) \\
&= \lim_{t\to\infty} \Bigg(1\  \underbrace{-\frac{1}{t+1}}_{-0} \Bigg) \\
&= 1
\end{align*}
Thus the series converges, namely to $1$.

Answer (score 2):

*This is too long for a comment.*

@marty cohen having done a nice generalization of the problem, making the story short, we should have
$$\sum_{n=1}^m \frac1{n(n+1)...(n+k-1)}=\frac{1}{(k-1)^2 \Gamma (k-1)}-\frac{\Gamma (m+1)}{(k-1) \Gamma (k+m)}$$ If $m\gg k$, using Stirling approximation
$$\frac{\Gamma (m+1)}{(k-1) \Gamma (k+m)}=\frac 1{(k-1)m^k}\left(m-\frac{1}{2} (k-1) k+\frac{(k-1) k (k+1) (3 k-2)}{24 m}+O\left(\frac{1}{m^2}\right) \right)$$

Using it with $k=10$ and $m=20$, the exact result is
$$\frac{2503751}{8177051282400}=3.061924\times 10^{-7}$$ while the approximation gives
$$\frac{1}{3265920}-\frac{131}{40960000000000}=\frac{63999331507}{209018880000000000}=3.061892\times 10^{-7}$$

As a consequence
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n(n+1)...(n+k-1)}=\frac{1}{(k-1)^2 \Gamma (k-1)}$$

Comment: $\frac{\Gamma (m+1)}{(k-1) \Gamma (k+m)} = \frac{1}{(k-1)(m+1)(m+2)\ldots(m+k-1)} \le \frac{1}{m}$, so you don't really need Stirling's approximation to show that this converges to zero if $m \to \infty$.